# Loading vagrant exported image - loads default, fresh image

Tags: vagrant

I am having problem loading my exported image.

As far as I remember - I installed what I want and exported using command

```
vagrant package
```

I have the image in the directory

```
E:\projektai\php projektai\htdocs
```

and named vagrant_image_exported

I have vagrant file here:

```
E:\other\dropbox\Dropbox\programavimas\kodo pavyzdziai\htdocs
```

and here is how I set to load my file in the vagrant file:

```
config.vm.box = "vagrant_image_exported"
config.vm.box_url = "file://e:/projektai/php projektai/htdocs/vagrant_image_exported"
```

I go with cygwin to the directory where is vagrantfile and run vagrant up.

Here is the output:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 3307 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version o                                                                       f
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you                                                                        see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within t                                                                       he
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed                                                                        on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.10
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.1
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => E:/other/dropbox/Dropbox/programavimas/kodo pavyzdziai/                                                                       htdocs
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--                                                                       provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still                                                                        run.
```

Then I login to vagrant with putty, and see there is nothing what I have installed :(
I really do not want to install my programas again. Thats why those image exports are, right?

So it looks that it loads something from default, but I dont have any idea how it knows where is the default image if I have commented in vagrant file:

```
 #config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
```

Where at least I should start to search what is wrong?

**Update:**

Asked another guy - he said that I should export taking the name from the virtual box, in my case this:

```
vagrant package --base htdocs_default_1418458570729_39510
```

I tried running this image by starting in virtual box and saw there is my installed programs - php, mysql.

After I created package again and login with putty, there is no php anymore.

Also tried going throught steps in this article:

http://abhishek-tiwari.com/hacking/creating-a-new-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-vm

Noticedd that I might not executed this:

```
vagrant box add package package.box
```

After executing and running vagrant up - still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I run my exported image.

Here is what I have done:

```
config.vm.box_url = "file:///e:/projektai/php projektai/htdocs/vagrant_image_exported"
```

Pay attention to 3 slashes after file. Saw in some example so used 3. Probably because 2 slashes are default, and 3rd is for root meaning, only after root goes e: ?

This was not enough.

I had to run

```
vagrant destroy
```

I did it in my directory where vagrantfile is. When not doing this, even when there is set new config.vm.box_url it was loading old image - the one which is empty - just downloaded from vagrant website images. There is .vagrant folder and might be that in this folder is saved something which points to old machine. And could be that after

vagrant destroy - this folder contents are affected and they do not point to old image but use which we set in config.vm.box_url .

So thats what I remember and believe what made it working. If I missed something, then maybe someone will add in the comments or new answer.

Also it is very unexpected behavior when you set new url but it is ignored, so I would like to know why vagrant is ignoring it. At least it could write a message in command line after running vagrant up, so we could understand.

**Update**

Found out that also you need to rename value of

```
config.vm.box
```

in vagrantfile.

Comment: ok just randomly found out that I needed to rename config.vm.box. I dont get why its not written in documentation